# How to Connect .NET Maui with django rest api?

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, maui

I have a django rest api running on 127.0.0.1:8000 and the endpoit of post request is 127.0.0.1:8000/add/ . I created a simple chatbot conversation in maui the point is the user will use maui interface to send msg to api and api respond will display on the interface . but I can't even connect them , I tried a lot but with no results .
Note : I check that my api is work fine by postman .
Note2 : When i send message to api I send it as json like this : {"name":"message"}.
Here is post request view :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def addItem(request):
  #  print("this is davinci methode",davinci("hi"))
    print("request data : ",request.data,"type of request.data ", type(request.data))
    name = request.data.get('name')
    print("name value: ", name)
    request.data['name']=davinci(request.data.get('name'))
    serializer =ItemSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    print("serializer data : ",serializer.data ,"type of serializer data : ",type(serializer.data) )

    return Response(request.data)
```

this the function in MainPage.xaml.cs to connect.

```
public async Task<string> SendToDjangoAPIAsync(string input)
    {
        Console.Write("Im in SendToDjangoAPI");
        input = "languge c";
        string apiURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var inputContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { name = input }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(apiURL, inputContent);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseData = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            Console.WriteLine(responseData["name"]);
            return responseData["name"];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Error connecting to the API. Status Code: {response.StatusCode}, Reason: {response.ReasonPhrase}");

        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to use the actual IP of the server,  it the loop back address

Comment: they both in the same machine , if the ip is wrong why when I use the same address of  127.0.0.1:8000/add/ in postman i got answer .

Comment: What sort of an env are you testing in - Android emulator, IOS device, etc?

Comment: right now I'm just testing on windows

Comment: Are you getting any http response code?  Or is it timing out?  Where is the client code for the connection?

Comment: I got some errors like internal server error or something like that, I add the code of function sendtodjango() i used in MainPage.xaml.cs .

Comment: Well, that is highly relevant info and not something you should just mention casually in a comment.  That is like going to the doctor for a headache and not mentioning that you were in a car wreck the day before.  That means the server has received your request and is encountering an error while processing it.  You need to either look at the logs or debug your server code to determine exactly what is happening.